# Override SonataUserBundle in app/Resources

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I try to follow Symfony best practices and put the templates in app/Resources/views, but I can't make it work for SonataUserBundle templates.

My AppBundle inherits SonataUserBundle.
If I put the template in:
`AppBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Security/login.html.twig` it works

But putting the login.html.twig file in 
`app/Resources/views/Admin/Security/login.html.twig` does not work.

I also tried:

```
app/Resources/views/AppBundle/Admin/Security/login.html.twig
app/Resources/views/SonataUserBundle/Admin/Security/login.html.twig
app/Resources/views/FOSUserBundle/Admin/Security/login.html.twig
```

Any idea? And Thanks for the help!

PS: The entity objects works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, I found the answer in the [FOSUserBundle documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md)...

```
app/Resources/views/FOSUserBundle/Admin/Security/login.html.twig
```

should actually be

```
app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Admin/Security/login.html.twig
```

The bundle name must be **BEFORE** the views directory...